# Julia: How to open a url into browser

Tags: url, julia

You can open a link in Python with the `webbrowser` library:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://example.com')
```

In Julia, I can use the `PyCall` package to run the Python library:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("PyCall")
using PyCall
@pyimport webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://example.com")
```

But is there a built-in function or package for Julia to open a link to your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality afaict but you can use the `open_in_default_browser` function from [LiveServer.jl](https://github.com/tlienart/LiveServer.jl/blob/9437513fad1ee2d41c81063d4ddb1be6f3e6f456/src/server.jl#L1-L25) (which in turn is from Pluto.jl).

```bash
$ julia -e 'using LiveServer; LiveServer.open_in_default_browser("https://example.com")'
```

I have `LiveServer.jl` installed in my root environment and it works great. I also use it to make a local web server using the `serve`. This is an alternative to using `python -m http.server` in a folder.

But if you don't want to install `LiveServer.jl`, you can just paste the code from LiveServer.jl into your `startup.jl` file.

```
function detectwsl()
    Sys.islinux() &&
    isfile("/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease") &&
    occursin(r"Microsoft|WSL"i, read("/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease", String))
end

function open_in_default_browser(url::AbstractString)::Bool
    try
        if Sys.isapple()
            Base.run(`open $url`)
            return true
        elseif Sys.iswindows() || detectwsl()
            Base.run(`cmd.exe /s /c start "" /b $url`)
            return true
        elseif Sys.islinux()
            browser = "xdg-open"
            if isfile(browser)
                Base.run(`$browser $url`)
                return true
            else
                @warn "Unable to find `xdg-open`. Try `apt install xdg-open`"
                return false
            end
        else
            return false
        end
    catch ex
        return false
    end
end
```

There's also https://github.com/tpapp/DefaultApplication.jl and https://github.com/mgkuhn/Desktop.jl which I haven't used but you may want to check out.

Comment: Thanks! For linux, this works if the user already has xdg-open, but some people do not have it and need to apt install it. But windows and mac works fine.

Comment: That's good to know! You can also check if `xdg-open` exists and it if doesn't you can check for other browsers on linux. This is what `Desktop.jl` does. I've modified the above answer to include that.

Comment: for running `Base.run(`cmd.exe /s /c start "" /b $url`)` on WSL windows, how do I make it so that it does not output 
```
'\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\foo\bar'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

Comment: You can use `success` instead of `Base.run` I think.

Comment: That works but if there is an error I cannot catch it?

Comment: Base.run will throw an error, but if you want to propagate it up you can remove the try catch from the code I shared above.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider `using Electron`:

```
using Electron
load(Window(), URI("https://github.com/julialang"))
```

Comment: this gives me the following error: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Most likely you have some problem with `PATH`s to libgtk on your Linux installation. You could try to rebuild Electron package `using Pkg;Pkg.build("Electron")`. Another thing I could try would be adding libgtk-3 to  your Linux installation and playing with PATHs. I do not have Linux however to replicate it.